How to function configMap in kubernetes?
I'm new to Kubernetes and I'm trying to use a configuration file used with Docker to actually make it work with kubernetes. I've seen that Config Map is used to do this. The application.conf file used with Docker is as follows:
[..]
analyzer {
  # Directory that holds analyzers
  urls = [
    "https://download.thehive-project.org/analyzers.json",
    "/opt/Custom-Analyzers/analyzers" 
  ]

  fork-join-executor {
    # Min number of threads available for analyze
    parallelism-min = 2
    # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
    parallelism-factor = 2.0
    # Max number of threads available for analyze
    parallelism-max = 4
  }
}

responder {
  # Directory that holds responders
  urls = [
    "https://download.thehive-project.org/responders.json",
    "/opt/Custom-Analyzers/responders" 
  ]

  fork-join-executor {
    # Min number of threads available for analyze
    parallelism-min = 2
    # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
    parallelism-factor = 2.0
    # Max number of threads available for analyze
    parallelism-max = 4
  }
}
[..]

I tried to repurpose this application.conf like this. The deployment.yaml:
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: cortex
  labels:
    app: cortex
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cortex
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cortex
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cortex
        image: thehiveproject/cortex:3.1.8-1
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9001
        env:
          - name: es_uri
            value: http://10.224.0.66:9200
          - name: start_docker
            value: "1"
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cortex-volume
          mountPath: /etc/cortex
      volumes:
      - name: cortex-volume
        configMap:
          name: cortex-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cortex
spec:
  selector:
    app: cortex
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 9001
      nodePort: 30010

    

The configmap.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cortex-config
data:
  analyzer.conf: |
    analyzer {
      # Directory that holds analyzers
      urls = [
        "https://download.thehive-project.org/analyzers.json",
        "/opt/Custom-Analyzers/analyzers" 
      ]

      fork-join-executor {
        # Min number of threads available for analyze
        parallelism-min = 2
        # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
        parallelism-factor = 2.0
        # Max number of threads available for analyze
        parallelism-max = 4
      }
    }

  responder.conf: |
    responder {
      # Directory that holds responders
      urls = [
        "https://download.thehive-project.org/responders.json",
        "/opt/Custom-Analyzers/responders" 
      ]

      fork-join-executor {
        # Min number of threads available for analyze
        parallelism-min = 2
        # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
        parallelism-factor = 2.0
        # Max number of threads available for analyze
        parallelism-max = 4
      }
    }

When I run these 2 files the pods goes into error and so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I hope you can help me.

As you've shown it, I'd expect the container filesystem to have two separate files, /etc/cortex/analyzer.conf and /etc/cortex/responder.conf, and anything else that might have been in /etc/cortex/ is probably hidden.  Does that match what you expect to happen?  In the first part of the question you discuss a single application.conf file.

@DavidMaze I tried to merge into a single file but it still gives me an error.

Looking into this docker hub link https://hub.docker.com/r/thehiveproject/thehive/, it tells to use /etc/thehive/application.conf as the mount point at the container. Try using the following config:
Configmap:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cortex-config
data:
  application.conf: |
    <put entire config here>

Deployment volumeMount config:
...
volumeMounts:
  - name: cortex-volume
    mountPath: /etc/thehive
...


The one you are referring to is no longer supported. now I saw that on docker these volumes are selected like this:
volumes:       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock       - /tmp/cortex-jobs:/tmp/cortex-jobs       - /opt/cortex/conf/application.conf:/etc/cortex/application.conf
